Écrire que + indicatif/subjonctif
Il y a une remarque dans un manuel scolaire :

Certains verbes, tels que dire, écrire, crier, prévenir (предупреждать), téléphoner, télégraphier peuvent, selon le sens, communiquer un fait ou exprimer un ordre. Dans le premier сas, ils demandent l’indicatif, dans le second, le Subjonctif.

Par exemple,

1. Criez-lui qu’elle a oublié son sac.
2. Elle les prévient qu’ils fassent attention,...

Dans un exercice il y a une phrase:

Écrivez-lui qu’il ne (devoir) pas perdre l’espoir.

Je ne vois pas de fait ici, donc j'ai conjugué doive, mais on m'a dit que j'avais eu tort. On m'a expliqué que devoir "remplaçait" lui-même le subjonctif (c'est comme je l'ai compris). Le subjonctif aurait été obligatoire s'il n'y avait pas eu devoir:

Écrivez-lui qu’il ne perde pas l’espoir

Moi, personnellement, je ne vois pas de grande différence sauf, peut-être, un peu plus de mélodrame avec "ne doive pas perdre".
Donc, indicatif (doit) ou subjonctif (doive) ?

Je pense avoir trouvé le « texte » (?) d'où sont tirées ces phrases,  les références semblent ciblées pour un public qui a des points de référence avec la langue russe (ukrainienne ?) et je trouve les explications très étranges (ce ne seraient pas les mêmes pour des apprenants anglophones, par exemples). Il y a peut-être dans cette langue  une spécificité  qui a nécessité cette explication qui doit laisser perplexes beaucoup de francophones.

@None C'est de l'ukrainien. Deux phrases qui se suivent dans un exercice page 113 : J'aime bien que mes amis conduisent vite, j'aime bien que mes amis boivent beaucoup :-)

@None, "votre" texte n'est pas celui duquel j'ai pris les extraits

Les francophones ne trouvent pas ces deux phrases un peu bizarres? crier quelqu'un? Vous dites ça?

@Lambie Pas de problème avec criez-lui.

@Lambie En revanche, je m'attends à un conditionnel ou un indicatif après Elle les préviens qu'ils ou il manque un pour: Elle les prévient pour qu’ils fassent attention.

@jlliagre Oui, d'accord.

@OldSkull Gramatika Popova-Kazakova?

Ce manuel présente curieusement la question (pour moi, natif de France): le remplacement par le subjonctif n'est pas régi par "certains verbes", il s'agit d'une règle générale de transposition au style indirect.
Le verbe à l'indicatif au style direct est transposé dans le même mode.
Le verbe à l'impératif au style direct est transposé au subjonctif.
Les exemples cités se transposent ainsi au style direct:

Criez-lui: "tu as oublié ton sac!" [indicatif];
Elle les prévient: "Faites attention!" [impératif].

D'où le l'indicatif (resp. subjonctif) dans les phrases au style indirect.
De même, l'exercice se transpose:

Ecris-lui: "tu ne dois pas perdre espoir." [indicatif].
Donc indicatif au style indirect comme expliqué dans la correction.

Le piège est que le sens ne change pas si je formule ainsi:

Ecris-lui: "ne perds pas espoir." [impératif].
Donc subjonctif au style indirect.

Toutefois il y a une différence grammaticale: le verbe de la prop. princ. n'est plus devoir à l'indicatif mais perdre à l'impératif. Or, c'est la grammaire qui régit la transposition au style indirect.
Ajouté après commentaires.

Certains verbes,  tels que dire, écrire, [...] peuvent, selon le sens, communiquer un fait ou
exprimer un ordre.

À mon avis, cette façon de dire est trompeuse. Les verbes dire, écrire etc. n'ont pas eux-mêmes le sens d'ordonner ou de décrire: ils ont le rôle d'introduire un message rapporté et c'est ce dernier qui, lui, a la possibilité d'être descriptif ou directif. On voit bien dans l'exemple suivant:

Les outrances du pauvre homme prirent alors des proportions bibliques. Le doigt du
Seigneur était [indic.] sur cette maison, sa ruine imminente; qu'elle renonçât [subj.]
sur le champ à ses infamies!

Rien n'introduit le discours indirect: il serait absurde de décrire le recours au subjonctif comme nécessité par le sens d'un verbe. Lequel, d'ailleurs? "prirent"?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

L'indicatif indique un état présent. le subjonctif une possibilité à venir:

Dans "Dites-lui qu'il ne fasse pas l'imbécile!", difficile de
remplacer "fasse" par fait".
Dans "dites-lui qu'il est stupide", on ne dira pas "...soit stupide"

Dans Ecrivez-lui qu’il ne doit/doive pas perdre l’espoir !

"doit" indique que la personne est en train de perdre espoir.     .
"doive" indique qu'il pourrait perdre espoir.

-------------------- Addendum :  --------------------
Il est difficle de qualifier "dire" ou "écrire" de verbes de tête ou verbes de coeur :

indicatif après les verbes de tête (constater, observer, croire,...),
subjonctif après les verbes de coeur (souhaiter, exiger,ordonner,vouloir,...).

Pour "Écrivez-lui qu’il ne doit/doive pas perdre l’espoir", on ne peut guère utiliser cette règle. Il faut alors se baser sur la formulation la plus naturelle compte tenu du contexte, c'est-à-dire "doit".
"doive" est bizarre, mais peut-être pas grammaticalement incorrect.
